# Docusign - Embedded Signing with multiple recipients in single document - ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, docusignapi, signing

I'm trying to implement docusign with embedded signing approach in ASP.Net Core using DocuSign.eSign.dll (3.0.1). I have been able to do it with single recipient but now I want that document to be signed by multiple recipients. Does anyone has working example who can share?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do have an example for you, but using node.JS and not C#, it's the same thing, just translate it to your lang. You can actually either see the live code here -https://loancosample.esigndemos.com and select the right most option (sailboat loan).
The source code is here - https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-loanco-nodejs. The specific one you looking for is here - https://github.com/docusign/sample-app-loanco-nodejs/blob/master/routes/loan-sailboat.js and I can copy/paste here the relevant code:

// Recipients
        var signer = new docusign.Signer();
        signer.routingOrder = 1;
        signer.email = body.inputEmail;
        signer.name = body.inputFirstName + ' ' + body.inputLastName;
        signer.recipientId = '1';
        signer.excludedDocuments = ['3'];

```
    if(body.inputSigningLocation == 'embedded'){
        signer.clientUserId = '1001';
    }
    if(body.inputAccessCode && body.inputAccessCode.length){
        signer.accessCode = body.inputAccessCode;
    }
    if(body.inputAuthentication == 'phone'){
        app.helpers.addPhoneAuthToRecipient(signer, body.inputPhone);
    }

    var appraiserSigner = new docusign.Signer();
    appraiserSigner.routingOrder = 2;
    appraiserSigner.email = body.inputAppraiserEmail;
    appraiserSigner.name = body.inputAppraiserFirstName + ' ' + body.inputAppraiserLastName;
    appraiserSigner.recipientId = '2';
```